# Using only CSS, any way to "flash" an element to draw attention after named anchor click?

Tags: css

I'm really not much of a web coder.  I'm struggling through modifying a shopping cart template.  I'm using a named anchor to get a user down to a detailed description area. That works fine, but the way it jumps is kind of disorienting and I'd like to draw attention to the heading.  Below is the div containing the named anchor.  I'd preferably like to flash #more_info_sheets (which is the heading) or else idTab1 (which is the content and also the anchor target)

```
<div id="bottom_more_info_block" class="mar_b2">
    <div id="more_info_block">
        <ul id="more_info_tabs" class="idTabs common_tabs li_fl clearfix">
            <li><a id="more_info_tab_more_info" href="#idTab1" class="selected">More info</a></li>
            <li><a href="#idTab5" class="idTabHrefShort">Comments(0)</a></li>
            <li><a href="#idTab311" id="st_easy_tab_1">Installation Instructions</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="more_info_sheets" class="sheets align_justify">
            <div id="idTab1" class="rte product_accordion open">
                [...subject content...]
            </div>
            <div style="display:none;">
                <div id="new_comment_form">
                    [...blahblah...]
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="idTab5" class="product_accordion block_hidden_only_for_screen">
                [...blahblah...]
            </div>
            <div id="idTab311" class="product_accordion block_hidden_only_for_screen">
                [...blahblah...]
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I have managed to do so far on my own is get the #idTab1 content to change to a yellow background when I click the link.  But now I'm stuck.  First off, I don't want it to stay highlighted.  Second, it isn't exactly a slick effect even if it did go away!  Third, I'd really rather flash the heading when clicked, rather than the #idTab1 itself.

```
#idTab1:target {
background-color: yellow; }
```

I found javascript based examples on the Web that seemingly do exactly what I want, but I can't seem to get Javascript to work with this cart so I'd rather not go there right now.

Comment: Once again, I search and struggle for hours only to find the solution seconds after posting a question for help.

Answer (score 2):

source:  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xfjrh

```
@import "compass/css3";

/**
 * Use the :target pseudo-element to apply
 * styles to the element with the same ID as  
 * the fragment identifier.
 * (e.g. `#target-section`)
 * 
 * The pseudo-element can also be used in
 * conjunction with another selector to 
 * define a variety of target styles.
 * (e.g. `#target-section:target)
 */

:target {
    -webkit-animation: target-fade 1s;
    -moz-animation: target-fade 1s;
    -o-animation: target-fade 1s;
    animation: target-fade 1s;
}


/**
 * Keyframe animation definition
 * 
 * 1. Insert a color of your choice here
 */

@-webkit-keyframes target-fade {
    from { background-color: red; } /* [1] */
    to { background-color: transparent; }
}

@-moz-keyframes target-fade {
    from { background-color: red; } /* [1] */
    to { background-color: transparent; }
}

@-o-keyframes target-fade {
    from { background-color: red; } /* [1] */
    to { background-color: transparent; }
}

@keyframes target-fade {
    from { background-color: red; } /* [1] */
    to { background-color: transparent; }
}




/* Demo-specific styles */
body {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```